# How to map nested objects in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have class structure similar to

Class1
{
Class2{
Attribute1
}
Class3
{
Attribute2
}
}

Now i have to map the html fields to the attributes how can I do the attributes under inner classes in thymeleaf springboot

Answer (score 1):

As long as your getters and setters are correctly set up, you can dot-walking to access inner objects and properties:

```
<span th:text="${class1.class2.attribute1}" />
<span th:text="${class1.class3.attribute2}" />
```

If you are using those attributes in a form, the same works for input fields.  For example:

```
<form th:object="${class1}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{class2.attribute1}" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, is it the same if we are populating values from UI to thos attributes that is <th:field input ${class1.class2.attribute}
Will the value store in that attribute?

Comment: @SivaramSurapureddy Yes, the same work for input fields.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Metroids seems to be correct. If you get an error, make sure again you have getters and setters in your Java classes and their modifier are `public`. Missing it is a common mistake. 
Also make sure this attributes are exists and you did not misstype it.
If you get `NullPointerException`, you should use `#{objects.nullsafe(variable)}` or use ?s like this: 
`<td th:text="${user?.address?.street}"></td>`

The ? means this object or attribute can be `null`.

I hope I could help you. :)